# How to I use the overloaded operator [] in the same class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, c++14

Example

```
class MyMap {
    std::map<K,V> m_map;
    public:
        void myFunc( K const& a, V const& b ) {
    
        // want to use [] operator on the current object.

        // something like this->[a] = b;
        }
    
        V const& operator[]( K const& key ) const {
            //body
        }
    }
```

How do I access the `MyMap` with a given `key` in the function `myFunc()` using `operator[]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dereference on `this`, e.g.

```
void myFunc( K const& a, V const& b ) {
    (*this)[a];
}
```

or call the `operator[]` in function-call syntax:

```
void myFunc( K const& a, V const& b ) {
    this->operator[](a);
}
```

BTW: The overloaded `operator[]` returns `V const&`, on which you can't perform assignment.

Comment: Another couple more options are `this->operator[](a);`, or `auto& self = *this; self[a];`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    // want to use [] operator on the current object.
>   // something like this->[a] = b;
> ```

You can use the operator using the object (`*this`), so

```
(*this)[a] = b;
```

or you can explicitly call the method `operator[]`,

```
this->operator[](a) = b;
(*this).operator[](a) = b;
```

But, as pointed by songyuanyao, remember to add the non-const version of `operator[]`,

```
    V & operator[] (K const & key)
     { return m_map[key]; }
```

if you want assign a new value to the returned reference.